# Will my Apple Wallet Pass generator work after my Apple Developer subscription is expired?

Tags: ios, wallet

I created an server side application which is generating PkPass files using Apple WWDRCA and Pass Type ID cert. My certificates are installed on the server and they are valid until end of 2017 but my Apple Developer account will expire in a few days. I'm wondering will my application continue to work without any issues or I will need to renew my subscription.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the description of the apple tag before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will continue to be able to issue and update passes until your certificate expires.  However, we have experienced problems with clients who have let their developer account lapse and have subsequently lost the PassTypeID.

If you anticipate the need to issue or update these particular passes after the expiry of your certificate, then I'd strongly recommend to renew your Apple developer account now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me the most important is to have it working because I'm not able to change it now but few days after, and with different account and certs. So if I understood very well, anyway it will work until certificates are valid?

Comment: Correct - it will continue to work.  It is also possible to transfer the PassTypeID to another developer team (account) and issue and update these passes with a certificate from the new team.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So even I accepted PassKit answer, here I want to add one note. The accepted answer is correct, no doubts, after my account expired, wallet file generator continued to work because certificates were valid and everything was just fine.

But what happened to me is either bad luck or I don't know. So, when my account expired as I said, everything was fine, except opening wallet files on iPhone. So I was always getting an error "Safari can't download this file". I tried everything but only one thing solved my problem:

**New developer account subscription**

After I order my new subscription I just generated new Pass Type certificate, updated my web service and server to work with new certs and with new team id and at that point I was able again to load my generated wallet files into iPhone Wallet App.